# Testing Android project with Ant

Tags: android, unit-testing, ant, junit

I have written an xml file "test_build.xml" to run all the test. I have compiled test files and compiled source files. I additionally require some jar files that used by my source/test files. I have included all these directories(compilied codes)/jars in path and use it as my class-path. I get a runtime exception.

< project name="myandroid" >

```
<path id="test.classpath">
    <pathelement path="a.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="tests"/> 
    <!-- other jars and directories -->
</path>
<target name="test-run" description="Run Test">
    <delete dir = "test_result" />
    <mkdir dir = "test_result" />
    <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="yes" showoutput="yes" >
        <classpath refid="test.classpath"/>
        <batchtest fork="yes" todir="test_result">
            <formatter type="xml"/>
            <fileset dir="tests">
                <include name="**/*.java"/>
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
</target>
```

I am running following command on commandline : 
ant "test-run" -f test_build.xml

Getting :

test-run:

```
[delete] Deleting directory test_result
[mkdir] Created dir: test_result
[junit] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
[junit]     at junit.framework.TestResult.<init>(TestResult.java:4)
[junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run(JUnitTestRunner.java:353)
[junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.launch(JUnitTestRunner.java:1052)
[junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.main(JUnitTestRunner.java:906)
[junit] Running RegexTest
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec
```

Answer (score 1):

The `android.jar` file that you use to create the application does only contain stub implementations.

```
public void something(...) { 
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!"); 
}
```

Stubbing the implementations reduces the size of the SDK a lot. This is fine for building an app as you still build against Android's public API. To finally execute your APK or run tests again, it must be deployed on either a device or emulator.

**Update**

To actually solve the problem you need an attached device or running emulator instance on your laptop. Verify that it's accessible by listing all available devices with `adb`:

```
$ adb devices
```

The `run-tests` target should automatically deploy your application on an emulator or device. If it does not you probably have to update your project first. The Android documentation, section [Running Tests](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_otheride.html#RunTestsCommand), states:

> You can use Ant to run all the tests in your test project, using the target run-tests, which is created automatically when you create a test project with the android tool.
>
> This target re-builds your main project and test project if necessary, **installs the test application to the current AVD or device**, and then runs all the test classes in the test application.
>
> You can update an existing test project to use this feature. To do this, use the android tool with the update test-project option.

Comment: well m a bit new in this and hence does not fully understand your answer. The test file uses Assert.assertEquals() from junit framework and one of the classes written by me in my source code. So, what should I do? install  the app on phone device. then? I have ant installed on my laptop.

Comment: thanks.. strangely changing the order of paths worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Invert your path declaration by placing the test classpath first !!!
should work properly ;-)